# how to pass variable from controller to model in PHP MVC

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller

i have been trying to pass some variables to model through the controller function so that the variable can be used in corresponding query from database.Here is my code

```
public function chooseGroup()
{
    $data['area']=$_GET['area']; //variable from a view source;this is loaded successfully in this function, i have printed an echo to be sure.
    $this->load->model('information_model',$data);
    $groupdata['rows']= $this->information_model->getGroupDetails();
  // var_dump($groupdata);
}
```

model code:

```
function getGroupDeatils() {
            $this->db->select('area'); //area is suppose to contain the value 
            $q = $this->db->get('group'); //group is the table name
            if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
                foreach ($q->result() as $rows) {
                    $data[] = $rows;
                }
            return $data;
        }
```

the value $data['area'] for some some reason isnt being recognized by the information_model and so the query is not processed.where did i go wrong?:(
please help!

Comment: show your view and model code

Comment: What does the constructor of `information_model` look like and what does the method `$this->load->model()` do???

Comment: $this->load->model() loads the information_model class where it is supposed to process the query! :(

Comment: can any one help to identify the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller your call to the model should be like below

```
public function chooseGroup()
{
    $data['area']=$_GET['area']; 
    $this->load->model('information_model');
    $groupdata['rows']= $this->information_model->getGroupDetails($data);
}
```

And then in your Model declare the method like below

```
function getGroupDetail($data) {
    // query code here
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! solved it exactly like this few hours ago! :)